generational zgc RES memory exceed container limit memory in jdk21
jvm options is
-XX:+UseZGC -XX:+ZGenerational 
-XX:ZCollectionInterval=30 -XX:ZAllocationSpikeTolerance=5 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow 
-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=70  -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70  
-Xss512k -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=256m 

container memory resource is
request: 4Gi
limit: 4Gi

the top command show the max process's RES is the below and container will exceed limit memory and be kill by node OOMKiller
VIRT: 70.4g
RES: 3.9g

another OOMKiller log(example)
Memory cgroup out of memory: 
Killed process 3007716 (java) 
total-vm:63711088kB, 
anon-rss:2447208kB, 
file-rss:26708kB, 
shmem-rss:1600868kB, 
UID:0 pgtables:9036kB 
oom_score_adj:912


In this image,we can understand PPS use is far below than RES,but it was closed by OOMKiller,because RES exceed container limit
I tried to change the below option ,but it didn't be fixed

MaxRAMPercentage to be smaller
add -XX:ZUncommitDelay=60
add -XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=2000m

I looked for some articals,all of they just said that zgc use multi-mapped memory.
But I can see the description that explain generational zgc don't use multi-mapped memory in https://openjdk.org/jeps/439

Where is the max heap setting?

-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70 this is the max heap setting in container,

Does this answer your question? Clarification of meaning new JVM memory parameters InitialRAMPercentage and MinRAMPercentage

sorry,this doesn't reslove the problem

Hi @69Naah, did you find an answer to your question ? The java wiki on ZGC does not mention  MaxRAMPercentage, only "Xmx", maybe that's the problem ?

@Sébastien Nussbaumer
I will use -Xmx to replace -XX:MaxRAMPercentage to try this.
I guess that they are same
